# Handling timeout exceptions when calling WCF services from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, exception

I am calling an ASMX web service using WCF from within my application - when a call to the web service fails, for example due to a timeout or connectivity issues, then the exception gets caught in the ApplicationUnhandledException method and does not pass to the Completed event handler.

What can I do to ensure that processing is passed to the Completed event handler on the web service proxy? Frustratingly there is an Error property on the xxxCompletedEventArgs class which leads me to believe it should pass back to this event handler rather than just throw an exception!

Comment: I can alter the Endxxx method in the Reference.cs to add a try/catch block, which allows me to recover, but I lose the error details in that case - I can't see what I need to do to get the e.Error property populated

Comment: Timeout exception work fine if to use WCF. But I don't know the answer why exceptions aren't sent to the Completed event. They should, at least in default configuration.

Comment: Isn't Reference.cs a generated file? Won't those chances be overwritten the next time you need to update your service reference?

Comment: @eremzeit I never said it was pretty :(

Comment: @DuncanWatts..Did you ever figure out how to handle the timeout exception? I'm having to write a trycatch in the Reference.cs like you but there must be a better way.

Comment: @rage afraid not, think I just left it with the exception handling in the Reference

Comment: @DuncanWatts I was able to handle the exception by checking the completedEvenArgs object in the completed event handler. That way i didn't have to mess with Reference.cs. Check out answer #10 in this link to see what i mean: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/handle-timeoutexception-silverlight-wcf-187824.aspx

Comment: @rage ahh that was the problem I was having originally, it wasn't making it to that point! Looks to be working fine for you then :)